# Disable option in select based on user selected value, Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to create simple option select. So far works just fine.

My code.

```
<%= select("post", "category", [["Latvija", "/lv?country_id=1"], ["Igaunija", "/lv?country_id=2"]] , {include_blank: false}, :class=>"styled", :'data-class'=>"pull-left",:name=>"products",:onchange=>"location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;") %>
```

Now I have 3 problems.

**1) How to exclude user selected option after he selects it.**
   At this point select looks like this:

```
 1) Latvija <= user selected

 2) Latvia  <= user already selected it so THIS selection shouldnt be here.

 3) Igaunija  <= valid option. User can switch back to other country
```

**2) How to show selected value like default "Select country" ?**
   I tried to add `:selected => @location.name` but it didn't work. `@location.name` is always aviable in all controllerers!!!

**UPDATE**: I came up with this solution: `{:include_blank => @location.name}` it kinda does what I need, but still I got multiple duplicates in aviable options. Now there is 3 duplicates to "Latvia"

**3) How to add dynamic values to those options ?** 
At this point I have like this:

```
["Latvija", "/lv?country_id=1"], ["Igaunija", "/lv?country_id=2"]
```

static values - `"/lv?country_id=1"` and `"/lv?country_id=2"`

As you can see there is locale "lv" in prefix. It is current language identifier. There is option to select english language. If after that user wants to change country (language params ) will be changed back to lv.

Any ideas to solve any of these problems ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `select_tag` in Rails and make your life easier.

Comment: @Humza Thanks. But how exactly it makes my life easier ?

Comment: Read the documentation, it has all the details for how you can pass options. And your current problem of selected option not appearing in the dropdown will also be fixed. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

Comment: @Humza Selected option APEARS in the dropdown in duplicate versions..

Comment: I mean it'll solve the problem of the selected option ALSO appearing in the dropdown.